# How can I animate elements with CSS that have been positioned with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, transition

UPDATE: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nodirtyrockstar/asrsxoek/6/)

P.S.: The CSS looks wonky in the fiddle, but the animation works. I am just trying to use CSS to make the movement more smooth and meet the requirement of using CSS.

I am writing a jQuery carousel for a technical skills screen. I've got it all done, except this one part. I could use a hint in the right direction. Essentially, the requirement is to animate the navigation through the images using CSS. Everything is built in JavaScript/jQuery. Here is the event listener/animation:

```
$('html').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 37 || e.keyCode === 38) {
    first = $('.slider li:first').detach();
    slider.append(first);
  }
  else if (e.keyCode === 39 || e.keyCode === 40) {
    last = $('.slider li:last').detach();
    slider.prepend(last);
  }
});
```

I have worked with [CSS 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#CSS_3) transitions before, but I never applied them to changes made by JavaScript. I've been trawling through the specifications, but it's pretty extensive. Is it possible to animate these movements, since they are not being positioned visually, but being reordered in the logic? If so, please help me figure out which property to animate. I tried using the 'all' property, but I don't think it's working. Here is the CSS I tried:

```
.slider li {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, transform 2s;
}
```

Finally, just in case you want to see the markup:

```
<ul class="slider">
  <li>
    <img src="https://lg-devtest.herokuapp.com/images/box_avatar.png">
    <div class="meta">
      <h2>Title: Avatar</h2>
      <p>IMDB Rating: 5.7</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://lg-devtest.herokuapp.com/images/box_quantum_of_solace.png">
    <div class="meta">
      <h2>Title: Quantum of Solace</h2>
      <p>IMDB Rating: 5.4</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://lg-devtest.herokuapp.com/images/box_breaking_bad.png">
    <div class="meta">
      <h2>Title: Breaking Bad</h2>
      <p>IMDB Rating: 7.4</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://lg-devtest.herokuapp.com/images/box_brick_mansions.png">
    <div class="meta">
      <h2>Title: Brick Mansions</h2>
      <p>IMDB Rating: 7.4</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://lg-devtest.herokuapp.com/images/box_gangs_of_new_york.png">
    <div class="meta">
      <h2>Title: Gangs of New York</h2>
      <p>IMDB Rating: 7.4</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `Essentially, the requirement is to animate the navigation through the images using CSS.` It's a little hard to follow what you want exactly, and how it is right now. Can you provide a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Will need all the relevant CSS (like `ul` styles) and JS (like the `slider` object).

Comment: You're using `detach`, `append` and `prepend`. Those are not CSS properties, and that is why the transition is not being applied.

Comment: CSS3 transitions can transition **numbers**; usually, transform/translate numbers taking something from one part of the screen to another. Changes to the layout aren't necessarily always going to be something it can smoothly transition, and/or is clear that it should be. There are experimental ideas I have involving absolutely-positioned, never-removed elements that get shifted around, and are "parented" by invisible static-positioned elements, but it's still pretty theoretical.

Comment: There is no animation in your code so there is nothing to apply transition on it